# check whether a class is disjoint or not with the given class using owl API

Tags: ontology, owl-api

I want to check class disjoint axioms using owl API.here my problem.suppose I have two classes **ChickenTopping** and **HamTopping**.ChickenTopping class has a subclass of axiom **hasSpiciness some Hot** and HamTopping class has a subclass of axiom **hasSpiciness some Mild**. these **Hot** and **Mild** classes are disjointed ones. due to that subclass of axioms, ChickenTopping and HamTopping classes are disjointed. so how can check whether the given HamTopping class is disjoint with Chicken class or not?

Comment: We don't have enouph assertions about your ontology to tell you other things instead of 'you should use a reasoner like Hermit, JFact or Openllet'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Galigator already mentioned a few reasoners you could use.

To check if a class is disjoint with another known class, once you create an `OWLReasoner`, you can use the following code:

```
OWLClass a = ...
OWLClass b = ...
OWLReasoner reasoner = ...
OWLDataFactory df = ...
OWLAxiom axiom = df.getOWLDisjointClassesAxiom(Arrays.asList(a, b));
boolean classesAreDisjoint = reasoner.isEntailed(axiom);
```